# Any easy way to convert traditional Chinese to simplified Chinese on Mac?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters

I am using OS X 10.9.2, is there any easy way to transfer traditional Chinese to simplified Chinese? Like some apps? I don't really like using website to do this.

Comment: What about Microsoft Word?

Comment: Better suited to superuser.se. This is really about how to use a mac.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, paste the traditional Chinese texts into Textedit, select those texts. Then Right-click the texts in Textedit, choose Services/Convert text to simplified Chinese.

Comment: That's right! I got it now.

Comment: I think you should use AppleScript if it's something that you often have to do.